# Load all element when previous is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a Map> of element like this

```
let list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to load one item, when the previous has finished loading.

I know how to do with one, but not how to chain the operation for all element in list

like

```
let index = 0;
let complete = false;
httpcall(list[index]).subscribe(() => {
    index++; 
    httpcall(list[index]).subscribe(() => {
        index++; 
        httpcall(list[index]).subscribe(() => {
            index++; 
            httpcall(list[index]).subscribe(() => {  
                index++; 
                httpcall(list[index]).subscribe(() => {  
                    completer = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something better ?

Comment: these all are get from same back-end service?

Comment: `let list = [` implies `list` is an array, but your accessor `list['id_'+index]` in the lower code implies that `list` is an *object*? Which is it?

Comment: @Asanka yes it s the same call

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes sorry, I just made a quick exemple but failed ahah, it's a Map of object where I want a particular item in the object. so I loop on the map

Comment: Wait, now it's a `Map`? To lookup items in a `Map`, you need to use `Map.get`

Comment: I am editing now. the point is, the format of the array/map don't matter, I know how to loop on it and get the item I want, My question is if there is a better way then a tree of subscription in order to do that

Comment: @Bobby why cant pass the whole array and get the result list? Instead of passing one by one?

Comment: because each element got a lot a value, so I prefer to load one list of item by one.

Comment: reducing the number of http calls increasing the angular performances. this is working but the performance is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an array of all items you want to iterate over, you can use `reduceRight` to create each callback, *starting from the end and working backwards*, passing the newly created callback along as the accumulator each time, so as to chain each `subscribe` call onto the end of the last one:

```
// Remove the first URL from the array,
// so that its `.subscribe` call can be used later to kick the process off
// once we've constructed the first callback for it:
const firstUrl = arr.shift();

const firstCallback = arr.reduceRight(
  // Reduce callback:
  (nextCallback, url) => () => {
    httpcall(url).subscribe(nextCallback);
  },
  // Initial value for accumulator, that is, the first `nextCallback`:
  () => {
    completer = true;
    // once this block is entered, everything is done
  }
);

// Now that we've constructed the first callback,
// we can start the process for real with `firstUrl`:
httpcall(firstUrl).subscribe(firstCallback);
```